# How do I create multiple Series from bound List of ChartValues<T> to one SeriesCollection in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, livecharts

I have managed to create all other charts in my application without creating view elements in viewmodel, but this one is giving me trouble.

I create list of list of objects in viewmodel and pass it as the datacontext for usercontrol containing the stacked column chart.

CartessianChart.Series is a SeriesCollection that is a collection, but doesn't have ItemsSource or equivalent property.
I have tried using ItemsControl and different kind of templates, but I can't find a working solution.

What I want:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart>
    <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
        Create this element below for every object in list
        <lvc:StackedColumnSeries Values="{Binding }" 
                                 Configuration="{x:Static mappers:mapper}"/>
    </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
</lvc:CartesianChart>
```

How I'm currently doing it:

```
VM.cs:
   Series = new SeriesCollection();

   foreach (ChartValues<object>objects in ListOfDataIwouldLikeToBindDirectly)
   {
       Series.Add(new StackedColumnSeries(sameStaticMapper)
           {
               Values = objects
           });
    }


View.xaml:
    <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding Series}"/>
```

Code looks like a mess and updating bound data gets difficult when I have to do it like this.

Thanks!

Comment: So how are you going to be able to add a dynamic number of series without using a loop and add them to a source collection of the view model or the `Series` collection of the control? What's the "mess"?

Comment: The code becomes a mess as this charts model logic is different than everything else in the project. Every data structure are entity frameworks types and they are stored as is and bound to LiveCharts Values fields with help of mappers and formatters. Everything needed are done by databases stored procedures. No data parsing logic required outside of mappers.

Comment: Maybe I'm just being oversensitive over code style. But since it's possible to loop over seriescollections and create multiple charts dynamically with templates, I was hoping there was some way to do it inside seriescollection with series as well.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your issue. You have to define the series somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably being hard to understand and also it's possible what I'm hoping simply isn't possible and I've understood something wrong as this my first wpf project. I want to define the series in xaml. I was hoping there is a possibility to achieve what I want with ItemsControl - ItemTemplate style control.

Here is non-dynamic example of Series defined in xaml from same project:
[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/7TDdjGV7)